# Abu-Bakrs, Omars, and 'Aishas in the offspring of Imam Ali

Tags: caliph, ali, ahl-ul-bayt, rashidi-caliphs

I heard that in the offspring of Imam Ali bin Abu-Talib (may Allah be pleased with him and honor his face), there were ones who were called:

- Abu-Bakr
- Omar
- 'Aisha

Is this true? could you mention them (or some at least)?

Answer (score 15):

Yes, this is true. I could mention:

**Abu-Bakrs** in the offspring of Imam Ali:

- Abu-Bakr, son of Imam Ali <sup>may Allah be pleased with him and honor his face</sup> himself and his wife Laila bint (daughter of) Mas'ud.<sup>[1](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=97299)</sup>
- [Abu-Bakr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abi_Bakr_ibn_Hasan), son of Imam Hasan bin Ali <sup>may Allah be pleased with both</sup>

**Omars** in the offspring of Imam Ali:

- Omar, son of Imam Ali himself and his wife Um Habibah bint Rabi'aa.<sup>[1](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=97299)</sup>
- Omar the senior and Omar the junior, sons of Imam Hussein bin Ali <sup>may Allah be pleased with both. [citation](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:8OEZkHfxEj0J%3aar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%B3%D9%8A%D9%86_%D8%A8%D9%86_%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%8A_%D8%A8%D9%86_%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%8A_%D8%B7%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk)</sup>
- Omar ibn Zain Al-Abideen Ali bin Hussein bin Ali <sup>[citation](http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%8A_%D8%A8%D9%86_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%B3%D9%8A%D9%86_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%AF#.D8.A3.D8.A8.D9.86.D8.A7.D8.A4.D9.87)</sup>

**'Aisha's** in the offspring of Imam Ali:

- 'Aisha bint Ali Al-Hadi <sup>[citation](http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%8A_%D8%A8%D9%86_%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%87%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%8A#.D9.86.D8.B3.D8.A8.D9.87)</sup>

I'll research and improve this question with more figures and citations, Allah willing.

Answer (score 4):

This names are usually used by Sunni Muslims to try to prove Imam Ali a.s. loved the Sunni Caliphs and named his children after them.

**About the Kuniyah Abubakr:**

About Abubakr it is not a name to be given by father of one to the child. Abubakr is a Kuniyah (title) which is given to one by people. Any one called Abubakr has another name. Also Abubakr was a popular Kuniyah used by many of Sahaba and was not a name specific to the Caliph (in Sunni view) Abubakr unlike today that this name is a specific name. If Imam Ali a.s. wanted to use the name of Caliph used his name (Abdu-Kaaba, Ateeq, Abdullah,..) and not his Kuniyah.  The name of this son was Abdullah and was martyred in Karbaka.

**Reference:**

> قتل عبد الله بن علي بن أبي طالب، وهو ابن خمس وعشرين سنة ولا عقب له.

الاصفهاني، أبو الفرج علي بن الحسين (متوفاي356)، مقاتل الطالبيين، ج 1، ص 22.

**About the name Umar:**

One of habits of Umar (the Caliph in Sunni view) was changing names of people and he changed name of son of Imam Ali a.s. to Umar.

**reference:**

> وكان عمر بن الخطاب سمّى عمر بن عليّ بإسمه.

البلاذري، أحمد بن يحيى بن جابر (متوفاي279هـ)، أنساب الأشراف، ج 1، ص 297.

> ومولده في أيام عمر. فعمر سماه باسمه.

الذهبي، شمس الدين محمد بن أحمد بن عثمان، (متوفاي748هـ)، سير أعلام النبلاء، ج 4، ص 134، تحقيق: شعيب الأرناؤوط، محمد نعيم العرقسوسي، ناشر: مؤسسة الرسالة - بيروت، الطبعة: التاسعة، 1413هـ.

Only 3 examples of changes of names of other people by Umar with Sunni references:

1. إبراهيم بن الحارث بـ عبد الرحمن.

> عبد الرحمن بن الحارث.... كان أبوه سماه إبراهيم فغيّر عمر اسمه.

العسقلاني الشافعي، أحمد بن علي بن حجر أبو الفضل (متوفاي852هـ)، الإصابة في تمييز الصحابة، ج 5، ص 29، تحقيق: علي محمد البجاوي، ناشر: دار الجيل - بيروت، الطبعة: الأولى، 1412 - 1992.

2. الأجدع أبى مسروق بـ عبد الرحمن.

> الأجدع بن مالك بن أمية الهمداني الوادعي... فسماه عمر عبد الرحمن.

العسقلاني الشافعي، أحمد بن علي بن حجر أبو الفضل (متوفاي852هـ)، الإصابة في تمييز الصحابة، ج 1، ص 186، رقم: 425، تحقيق: علي محمد البجاوي، ناشر: دار الجيل - بيروت، الطبعة: الأولى، 1412 - 1992.

3- ثعلبة بن سعد بـ معلي:

> وكان إسم المعلى ثعلبة، فسماه عمر بن الخطاب المعلى.

الصحاري العوتبي، أبو المنذر سلمة بن مسلم بن إبراهيم (متوفاي: 511هـ)، الأنساب، ج 1، ص 250.

**About name Uthman:**

Imam Ali (a.s) himself said that:

> I named my son Uthman for my brother Uthman Ibn Mzoun

**Sunni reference**

> إنّما سمّيته بإسم أخي عثمان بن مظعون.

الاصفهاني، أبو الفرج علي بن الحسين (متوفاي356)، مقاتل الطالبيين، ج 1، ص 23.

Also Ibn Hajar Asqalani recorded the names of 26 of sahaba with name of Uthman:

> . عثمان بن ابوجهم الأسلمي؛ 2. عثمان بن حكيم بن ابوالأوقص؛ 3. عثمان بن
>   حميد بن زهير بن الحارث؛ 4. عثمان بن حنيف بالمهملة؛ 5. عثمان بن ربيعة
>   بن أهبان؛ 6. عثمان بن ربيعة الثقفي؛ 7. عثمان بن سعيد بن أحمر؛ 8. عثمان
>   بن شماس بن الشريد؛ 9. عثمان بن طلحة بن ابوطلحة؛ 10. عثمان بن ابوالعاص؛
>   11. عثمان بن عامر بن عمرو؛ 12. عثمان بن عامر بن معتب؛ 13. عثمان بن عبد غنم؛ 14. عثمان بن عبيد الله بن عثمان؛ 15. عثمان بن عثمان بن الشريد؛
>   16. عثمان بن عثمان الثقفي؛ 17. عثمان بن عمرو بن رفاعة؛ 18. عثمان بن عمرو الأنصاري؛ 19. عثمان بن عمرو بن الجموح؛ 20. عثمان بن قيس بن
>   ابوالعاص؛ 21. عثمان بن مظعون؛ 22. عثمان بن معاذ بن عثمان؛ 23. عثمان بن
>   نوفل زعم؛ 24 . عثمان بن وهب المخزومي؛ 25. عثمان الجهني؛ 26. عثمان بن
>   عفان.

**reference:**

العسقلاني، أحمد بن علي بن حجر أبو الفضل الشافعي، الإصابة في تمييز الصحابة، ج 4، ص 447 ـ 463، تحقيق: علي محمد البجاوي، ناشر: دار الجيل - بيروت، الطبعة: الأولى، 1412 - 1992

Also the names you mentioned were popular names at that time and does not mean being about Sunni Caliphs.

Also names of children of Imams are not recorded clearly and there are different narrations about number and names of their children that all of them are not authentic.

Also some Shia scholars say Imams sometimes names their children with Sunni names and even married to families of Sunni kings of their times in order to make unity between Shia and Sunni against enemies of Islam and prevent civil wars that lead in weakening of Islam that harms both Shia and Sunni and Islam generally. Like prophet that marries to different tribes of Arabs to unite them in Islam.

An important question from Sunni brothers in this regard is if naming means loving so those who claim to love Ahl Bayt like Umayyads, etc. how many of their children are named after them by names like Ali, Hussain, Fatima,...?

Also Sahih Bukhari says Ali a.s. did not give bayat to Abuabkr until 6 months that peoves he had conflict with Abubakr.

**More Sunni references and detailed answer:**

- [www.valiasr-aj.com](http://www.valiasr-aj.com/fa/page.php?id=437&bank=question&startrec=2)

Comment: I would recommend that you add the referenced text in English, since many folks here are non-Arabs and this forum itself is in English, and it would make sense for all to understand which books you are furnishing references from. At the very least ensure that the references (if not the text) are in English.

Comment: @BattleofKarbala "An important question from sunni brothers in this regard is if naming means loving so those who claim to love Ahl Bayt like Umayyads, etc how many of their children are named after them by names like Ali, Hussain, Fatima,...?"...Ali is the 4th most common male name in Turkey, a sunni country. Hussain is the 5th and Hasan is the 6th most common name. Also, Fatima is the most common female name. You may want to take a look at the list over here: http://www.ismininanlaminedirx.com/turkiyede-en-cok-kullanilan-isimler-8139/

Comment: @Artus Turkey is not Bani umayya , right ?

Comment: @Artus Regular cursing on Ali is certainly not the best way to express our love for Ahl al Bayt. 
 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umayyad_tradition_of_cursing_Ali?wprov=sfla1)